# How to run OpenTk in Vs 2008?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, opengl, opentk

i try to learn OpenTk (Old Version Tao Framework) But i can not simple draw Line :

```
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
using OpenTK.Audio;
using OpenTK.Audio.OpenAL;
using OpenTK.Input;

namespace Test1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void glControl1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
// COORDINATE SYSTEM ALGORITHM:
            GL.ClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            GL.ShadeModel(ShadingModel.Flat);
            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

            glControl1.SwapBuffers();
            GL.Begin(BeginMode.Lines);
            GL.Vertex2(0.0, -1.0);
            GL.Vertex2(0.0, 1.0);
            GL.Vertex2(1.0, 0.0);
            GL.Vertex2(-1.0, 0.0);
            GL.End();
        }

    }
}
```

i can not watch coordinate system. i think that can not run open tk in vs 2008? what is your best advise?

Answer (score 1):

Several things :

- This has nothing to do with Visual C# 2008, which is perfectly capable of compiling C# code.
- You do not set the color in which you want to paint the line. Write GL.Color3(1,0,0); just before GL.Begin
- SwapBuffers puts what you've just drawn onscreen. In your case, it is the result of glClear = a white screen. Your following commands are anihilated by the glClearColor that happens just after (1rst line of your function)
- You need to tell OpenGL how to transform your vertices in space. ( In this case, it should work, but that's a coincidence ). Read about glMatrixMode, glLoadIdentity, glOrtho/gluLookAt, glTranslate in any tutorial (basically : matrixmode(PROJECTION); loadidentity; glOrtho(-1,1,-1,1,-1,1);matrixmode(MODELVIEW);loadIdentity;translate(asYouWish) )

Answer (score 0):

It will run in VS2008.

There's some good OpenTK starting code here that walks you through proper setup of a Winform + GLControl and some simple rendering.  (It should be enough to let you sort out the various issues Calvin pointed out.)

http://www.opentk.com/doc/chapter/2/glcontrol